# Make Phone call from listview item click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

in my app I am loading phone numbers from database to listview, this is done and work fine. Now I want when user click at any number in listview the app must dialing the selected number. How to get the list item value and make call directly when clicked.

```
 String[] myArr = (String[])records.ToArray(typeof(string));
        //setting array adapter with item layout
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.item, Resource.Id.itemTxt, (System.Collections.IList)records);
        list.SetAdapter(adapter);  // setting adapter to list view

        list.ItemClick += List_ItemClick;
    }

    void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e )
    {
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" +???? );
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Android get object properties from ListView click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551367/xamarin-android-get-object-properties-from-listview-click-event)

Comment: thank. its work fine